# bell curve method refactoring

Tags: ruby

Assuming three known attributes:

- limit (the number of cases on the edge)
- array of total case ids
- the focus of analysis (top, middle, bottom)

can the following method be refactored better:

```
  array_size = ids.size
  if context == 'top'
    ids = ids[0..params[:limit].to_i])
  elsif context == 'bottom'
    ids = ids.pop( ( array_size - params[:limit].to_i ) )
  else
    remove_top = ids.drop( ( params[:limit].to_i / 2).round )
    remove_bottom = ids.pop( ( array_size - (params[:limit].to_i / 2).round ) )
    ids = (ids - ( remove_top + remove_bottom ) ))
  end
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to compute. What does this have to do with bell curves? What is meant by "cases on the edge"? How are "top", "middle" and "bottom" defined? You need to state your question in words then, if you think it is necessary or would be helpful, give an example (including the desired result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my assumptions, based on what you've given us:

- `ids` is the array
- `limit` is less than the size of the array
- you meant to have `...` instead of `..` in your `top` so that it returns the correct number of elements (elements are numbered from 0)

```
array_size = ids.size
limit_size = params[:limit].to_i

if context == 'top'
  start_pos = 0
  end_pos = limit_size
elsif context == 'bottom'
  start_pos = array_size - limit_size
  end_pos = array_size
else
  start_pos = (limit_size.to_f/2).ceil
  end_pos = array_size - limit_size/2 - 1
end

ids = ids[start_pos...end_pos]
```

Comment: Helpful thinking for refactoring into sub method.  Note:  https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Array.html#class-Array-label-Accessing+Elements  `..` allows accessing index values, thus the above statement should've been `ids[0..(params[:limit].to_i] - 1))

Comment: @Jerome what do you mean? Triple dot (`...`) Ranges are exclusive, meaning they will not contain the last element. The issue with your solution is imagine `a = [1,2,3]` and `limit = 0` well `a[0...limit] #=> []` but `a[0..(limit -1)] => [1,2,3]`

Comment: 'meaning they will not contain the last element'; clarification is useful.  The ruby reference linked does not indicate that per se...

Comment: I don't understand the question, so cannot comment on the validity of your code, but assuming it is correct consider writing `rng = case context; when 0; 0..limit_size; when "bottom"; limit_size..array_size]; else; ...' end`, then `ids = ids[rng]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the concept (as I understand it) is "top" = first N, "bottom" = last N, "mid"(?) = size + N < mid < size - N. I am certain you can come up with something clever :)

Comment: @engineersmnky, thank you, that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a misunderstanding as to the meaning of 'limit'.  Here the intent is to define the desired set.  Hence, the collection for the `middle` context needs to be adjusted

```
array_size = ids.size
limit_size = params[:limit].to_i
mid_size = array_size - limit_size

if context == 'top'
  start_pos = 0
  end_pos = limit_size
elsif context == 'bottom'
  start_pos = array_size - limit_size
  end_pos = array_size
else
  start_pos = (mid_size.to_f/2).floor  
  end_pos = array_size - (mid_size/2)
end

ids = ids[start_pos...end_pos]
```

the handling of `floor` or `ceil` and the `-1` for index position is pertinent when the limit is an odd number.  The choice is based on whether one wants to include or not the odd-numbered object & on which end of the scale one wants to extract from.